# Order result with LIKE operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, sql-like

In SQL Server, I can use this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE Country LIKE '%land%';
```

This query will return values that contains string `land`.

Is it possible to sort returned values by position of string `land`?

Example:

Input values : "New Zealand, USA, Landcountry, Alandia"

Output values : "Landcountry, Alandia, New Zealand"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country LIKE '%land%'
order by charindex('land', Country)
```

Comment: yes, this is what i can't remember. And one more question : if instead of "land" i use "_" symbol which means any char, then result will be not changed? Output will be as Input?

Comment: AND what about case when in table we have data like : "Landcountry" and  "Landry" - First would be "Landcountry" as i tested. Or maybe i am wrong? So how can i output firstly "Landry" and then  "Landcountry" ? Thanks